# Google API integration into xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c

Add Files to "Quickstart"..., add the following projects to the workspace from the libraries you cloned in the previous step: `google-api-objectivec-client/Source/GTL.xcodeproj`

```
--> There isn't any GTL.codeproj, there is GTLCore.xcodeproj instead.
```

This makes it impossible to reproduce the following steps in the tutorial:

```
d- Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target and make the following changes:
   Add the library GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries.

e- Delete the "GTL" project's "GTLFramework" target.

f- In the Project navigator, delete GTL project's GTL Source > Common > HTTPFetcher group.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out the code. To do this, you can just run svn checkout
   http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
   google-api-objectivec-client-read-only from your terminal. I will
   refer to this code as "Google's code".
2. Go to your project's Build Phases. Expand "Link Binary With
   Libraries" and add Security.framework and
   SystemConfiguration.framework. These two are required by Google's
   code.
3. Go to your project's Build Settings. Using the search box there,
   look for Other Linker Flags (make sure "All" is selected to the left
   of the search box). Add -ObjC -all_load.
4. Now search for User headers search path and add the full path to
   Google's /Source directory. Make sure you select recursively.
5. Using Finder, go to Google's /Source/OAuth2/Touch directory. Drag
   and drop GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib into your project.
6. Go back to Finder and go to Google's /Source directory. Drag and
   drop GTLCommon_Sources.m and GTLCommon_Networking.m into your
   project.
7. Now, you need to import the files for the services you want to use.
   In my case, I need to use Google Drive, so I'll add those. In
   finder, go to Google's /Source/Services/Drive/Generated directory.
   Drag and drop GTLDrive.h and GTLDrive_Sources.m into your project.
   If you want to use other services, go to their directory and import
   the appropriate .h and .m file.
8. For some reason, Google's code doesn't use ARC, so if you try to
   build right now, you will get ARC compile errors. So we need to
   disable ARC for Google's code only. To do this, go back to your
   project's Build Phases, but this time expand "Compile Sources". Make
   sure that GTLCommon_Sources.m and GTLCommon_Networking.m are there.
   Select them, press enter and type in -fno-objc-arc. This will
   disable ARC for both of them. Make sure you don't add this option
   for any other file (unless you know what you're doing).
9. You are done! Now, whenever you want to use Google's API, just
   import GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h and your service header. In my
   case, since I'm using Google Drive, I will also import GTLDrive.h.